# How to save the amount of lives when the player dies and then uses one life?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I'm struggling with this issue.I searched a lot before asking here.

So i have programmed an arcade game which when it dies it pops up a menu with a continue option using one life out of five.Like Subway Surfers with the keys.

The issue is that when i use one heart i want to save it.But everytime i restart the game it keeps saying the initial number which is five.Or without using a life,it by itself,subtracts by one without even clicking the "Save me" button.

Here is my code:

```
public Text heart;
public Text heart2;

public int counter;




void Start () {

    heart.text = "" + counter;
    heart2.text = "" +counter;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void SaveMe()
{
    heart.text = counter.ToString();
    heart2.text = counter.ToString();
    int heartScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Life2", 0);
    heartScore--;
    if(heartScore<0)
    {
        heartScore = counter;
    }
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Life2", heartScore);
    heart.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Life2", 0).ToString();
    heart2.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Life2", 0).ToString();
}
```

}

Then i call this method in the button script.

Comment: Aren't you missing a `PlayerPrefs.Save()`?

Answer (score 1):

You should need to save life counter in a file or [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) in unity so that loading a scene doesn't effect the counters.

> Stores and accesses player preferences between game sessions.

Comment: Ok,but i will be very grateful if you help me a little bit  with the code :)

Comment: I am unable to understand your question/code correctly please improve it. so i will check it

Comment: I tried everything but it won't work.Honestly,I no more have  an idea how this will work

Answer (score -1):

When Unity loads a new scene (if not in an additive way) it will destroy everything that belongs to it before loading the new one. If you don't want a GameObject to be destroyed automatically, read the instructions for [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)

Also consider generally to separate your game model (in this occasion the variable counter) to a different Component and use [scriptable objects](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects) for managing it/them. It will make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: So .. what exactly has that to do with the question?

Comment: Misread question, I assumed scene was reloaded when restarting the game, Thanks for the pointer :)

Comment: Ok if i have to put counter in a scriptable objects script how will it happen?Can you help me with the code?